# Solving linear equation system with sympy takes forever

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, sympy, symbolic-math

I have a linear equation system consisting of 3 equations as a result of a matrix multiplication. The equation system has 3 unknowns and 24 input variables. In theory, it should be solvable, however, `linsolve` takes forever (roughly a day so far) to calculate a solution.

Here  is my sympy input:

```py
from sympy import Matrix, symbols, pprint, Eq, linsolve
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdastr

n2_x, n2_y, n2_z, o2_x, o2_y, o2_z, a2_x, a2_y, a2_z, p2_x, p2_y, p2_z = symbols('n2_x n2_y n2_z o2_x o2_y o2_z a2_x a2_y a2_z p2_x p2_y p2_z', real=True)
T_2 = Matrix([[n2_x, o2_x, a2_x, p2_x], [n2_y, o2_y, a2_y, p2_y], [n2_z, o2_z, a2_z, p2_z], [0,0,0,1]])
n3_x, n3_y, n3_z, o3_x, o3_y, o3_z, a3_x, a3_y, a3_z, p3_x, p3_y, p3_z = symbols('n3_x n3_y n3_z o3_x o3_y o3_z a3_x a3_y a3_z p3_x p3_y p3_z', real=True)
T_3 = Matrix([[n3_x, o3_x, a3_x, p3_x], [n3_y, o3_y, a3_y, p3_y], [n3_z, o3_z, a3_z, p3_z], [0,0,0,1]])
p_x, p_y, p_z = symbols('p_x p_y p_z', real=True)
R_p = Matrix([[0, 0, 0, p_x], [0, 0, 0, p_y], [0, 0, 0, p_z], [0,0,0,1]])

eq1 = (Matrix.eye(4)-T_2*T_3**-1)*R_p
eq2 = Eq(eq1[0, 3], 0)
eq3 = Eq(eq1[1, 3], 0)
eq4 = Eq(eq1[2, 3], 0)

res = linsolve([eq1[0, 3], eq1[1, 3], eq1[2, 3]], (p_x, p_y, p_z))
pprint(res)
print(res)
```

How can I speed up solving the problem, or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: As background information: `T_2` and `T_3` are transformation matrices, `R_p` is also a transformation matrix, but with (known) zero rotation. We are looking for the translation only.

Comment: The expression `T_3**-1` for a 4x4 matrix with 12 unknowns is rather heavy. Is there a possibility to write the equations without the need of calculating the inverse?

Answer (score 2):

I do concur with JohanC that it might be worth considering a different way of approaching this since the expressions you are asking for are enormous. If you know anything more specific about any relationship between the symbols then it can be better to use that information up front.

Looking at the answer (below) there seems to be a clear repetitive structure to it that would suggest that there could be a more intelligent way of computing that result rather than just slinging the whole system of arbitrary symbols into sympy. I expect that finding an expression for the `i,j` element of your matrix would lead to a shorter result involving indices and summations.

That being said there have been a lot of improvements in the performance of `linsolve` in sympy 1.7 and since (i.e. the current master branch that will at some point become 1.8). I expect further improvements after 1.8 as well.

With the (almost-)current sympy master branch I tried this and got a solution in around 1 minute:

```
In [33]: %time res = linsolve([eq1[0, 3], eq1[1, 3], eq1[2, 3]], (p_x, p_y, p_z))
CPU times: user 42.7 s, sys: 1.23 s, total: 43.9 s
Wall time: 51.2 s
```

Note that the first time I tried it took 1 minute. When I tried again after quitting Python and updating to the absolute latest sympy master it took a lot longer (not sure how long). I don't think anything should have changed but it's possible that the time taken is non-deterministic somehow.

The answer I found is:

```
In [41]: str(res)
Out[41]: 'FiniteSet(((a2_x*n2_y*o2_z*p3_x - a2_x*n2_y*o3_x*p2_z + a2_x*n2_y*o3_x*p3_z - a2_x*n2_y*o3_z*p3_x - a2_x*n2_z*o2_y*p3_x + a2_x*n2_z*o3_x*p2_y - a2_x*n2_z*o3_x*p3_y + a2_x*n2_z*o3_y*p3_x + a2_x*n3_x*o2_y*p2_z - a2_x*n3_x*o2_y*p3_z - a2_x*n3_x*o2_z*p2_y + a2_x*n3_x*o2_z*p3_y - a2_x*n3_x*o3_y*p2_z + a2_x*n3_x*o3_y*p3_z + a2_x*n3_x*o3_z*p2_y - a2_x*n3_x*o3_z*p3_y - a2_x*n3_y*o2_z*p3_x + a2_x*n3_y*o3_x*p2_z - a2_x*n3_y*o3_x*p3_z + a2_x*n3_y*o3_z*p3_x + a2_x*n3_z*o2_y*p3_x - a2_x*n3_z*o3_x*p2_y + a2_x*n3_z*o3_x*p3_y - a2_x*n3_z*o3_y*p3_x - a2_y*n2_x*o2_z*p3_x + a2_y*n2_x*o3_x*p2_z - a2_y*n2_x*o3_x*p3_z + a2_y*n2_x*o3_z*p3_x + a2_y*n2_z*o2_x*p3_x - a2_y*n2_z*o3_x*p2_x - a2_y*n3_x*o2_x*p2_z + a2_y*n3_x*o2_x*p3_z + a2_y*n3_x*o2_z*p2_x - a2_y*n3_x*o3_z*p2_x - a2_y*n3_z*o2_x*p3_x + a2_y*n3_z*o3_x*p2_x + a2_z*n2_x*o2_y*p3_x - a2_z*n2_x*o3_x*p2_y + a2_z*n2_x*o3_x*p3_y - a2_z*n2_x*o3_y*p3_x - a2_z*n2_y*o2_x*p3_x + a2_z*n2_y*o3_x*p2_x + a2_z*n3_x*o2_x*p2_y - a2_z*n3_x*o2_x*p3_y - a2_z*n3_x*o2_y*p2_x + a2_z*n3_x*o3_y*p2_x + a2_z*n3_y*o2_x*p3_x - a2_z*n3_y*o3_x*p2_x - a3_x*n2_x*o2_y*p2_z + a3_x*n2_x*o2_y*p3_z + a3_x*n2_x*o2_z*p2_y - a3_x*n2_x*o2_z*p3_y + a3_x*n2_x*o3_y*p2_z - a3_x*n2_x*o3_y*p3_z - a3_x*n2_x*o3_z*p2_y + a3_x*n2_x*o3_z*p3_y + a3_x*n2_y*o2_x*p2_z - a3_x*n2_y*o2_x*p3_z - a3_x*n2_y*o2_z*p2_x + a3_x*n2_y*o3_z*p2_x - a3_x*n2_z*o2_x*p2_y + a3_x*n2_z*o2_x*p3_y + a3_x*n2_z*o2_y*p2_x - a3_x*n2_z*o3_y*p2_x - a3_x*n3_y*o2_x*p2_z + a3_x*n3_y*o2_x*p3_z + a3_x*n3_y*o2_z*p2_x - a3_x*n3_y*o3_z*p2_x + a3_x*n3_z*o2_x*p2_y - a3_x*n3_z*o2_x*p3_y - a3_x*n3_z*o2_y*p2_x + a3_x*n3_z*o3_y*p2_x + a3_y*n2_x*o2_z*p3_x - a3_y*n2_x*o3_x*p2_z + a3_y*n2_x*o3_x*p3_z - a3_y*n2_x*o3_z*p3_x - a3_y*n2_z*o2_x*p3_x + a3_y*n2_z*o3_x*p2_x + a3_y*n3_x*o2_x*p2_z - a3_y*n3_x*o2_x*p3_z - a3_y*n3_x*o2_z*p2_x + a3_y*n3_x*o3_z*p2_x + a3_y*n3_z*o2_x*p3_x - a3_y*n3_z*o3_x*p2_x - a3_z*n2_x*o2_y*p3_x + a3_z*n2_x*o3_x*p2_y - a3_z*n2_x*o3_x*p3_y + a3_z*n2_x*o3_y*p3_x + a3_z*n2_y*o2_x*p3_x - a3_z*n2_y*o3_x*p2_x - a3_z*n3_x*o2_x*p2_y + a3_z*n3_x*o2_x*p3_y + a3_z*n3_x*o2_y*p2_x - a3_z*n3_x*o3_y*p2_x - a3_z*n3_y*o2_x*p3_x + a3_z*n3_y*o3_x*p2_x)/(a2_x*n2_y*o2_z - a2_x*n2_y*o3_z - a2_x*n2_z*o2_y + a2_x*n2_z*o3_y - a2_x*n3_y*o2_z + a2_x*n3_y*o3_z + a2_x*n3_z*o2_y - a2_x*n3_z*o3_y - a2_y*n2_x*o2_z + a2_y*n2_x*o3_z + a2_y*n2_z*o2_x - a2_y*n2_z*o3_x + a2_y*n3_x*o2_z - a2_y*n3_x*o3_z - a2_y*n3_z*o2_x + a2_y*n3_z*o3_x + a2_z*n2_x*o2_y - a2_z*n2_x*o3_y - a2_z*n2_y*o2_x + a2_z*n2_y*o3_x - a2_z*n3_x*o2_y + a2_z*n3_x*o3_y + a2_z*n3_y*o2_x - a2_z*n3_y*o3_x - a3_x*n2_y*o2_z + a3_x*n2_y*o3_z + a3_x*n2_z*o2_y - a3_x*n2_z*o3_y + a3_x*n3_y*o2_z - a3_x*n3_y*o3_z - a3_x*n3_z*o2_y + a3_x*n3_z*o3_y + a3_y*n2_x*o2_z - a3_y*n2_x*o3_z - a3_y*n2_z*o2_x + a3_y*n2_z*o3_x - a3_y*n3_x*o2_z + a3_y*n3_x*o3_z + a3_y*n3_z*o2_x - a3_y*n3_z*o3_x - a3_z*n2_x*o2_y + a3_z*n2_x*o3_y + a3_z*n2_y*o2_x - a3_z*n2_y*o3_x + a3_z*n3_x*o2_y - a3_z*n3_x*o3_y - a3_z*n3_y*o2_x + a3_z*n3_y*o3_x), (a2_x*n2_y*o2_z*p3_y - a2_x*n2_y*o3_y*p2_z + a2_x*n2_y*o3_y*p3_z - a2_x*n2_y*o3_z*p3_y - a2_x*n2_z*o2_y*p3_y + a2_x*n2_z*o3_y*p2_y + a2_x*n3_y*o2_y*p2_z - a2_x*n3_y*o2_y*p3_z - a2_x*n3_y*o2_z*p2_y + a2_x*n3_y*o3_z*p2_y + a2_x*n3_z*o2_y*p3_y - a2_x*n3_z*o3_y*p2_y - a2_y*n2_x*o2_z*p3_y + a2_y*n2_x*o3_y*p2_z - a2_y*n2_x*o3_y*p3_z + a2_y*n2_x*o3_z*p3_y + a2_y*n2_z*o2_x*p3_y - a2_y*n2_z*o3_x*p3_y - a2_y*n2_z*o3_y*p2_x + a2_y*n2_z*o3_y*p3_x + a2_y*n3_x*o2_z*p3_y - a2_y*n3_x*o3_y*p2_z + a2_y*n3_x*o3_y*p3_z - a2_y*n3_x*o3_z*p3_y - a2_y*n3_y*o2_x*p2_z + a2_y*n3_y*o2_x*p3_z + a2_y*n3_y*o2_z*p2_x - a2_y*n3_y*o2_z*p3_x + a2_y*n3_y*o3_x*p2_z - a2_y*n3_y*o3_x*p3_z - a2_y*n3_y*o3_z*p2_x + a2_y*n3_y*o3_z*p3_x - a2_y*n3_z*o2_x*p3_y + a2_y*n3_z*o3_x*p3_y + a2_y*n3_z*o3_y*p2_x - a2_y*n3_z*o3_y*p3_x + a2_z*n2_x*o2_y*p3_y - a2_z*n2_x*o3_y*p2_y - a2_z*n2_y*o2_x*p3_y + a2_z*n2_y*o3_x*p3_y + a2_z*n2_y*o3_y*p2_x - a2_z*n2_y*o3_y*p3_x - a2_z*n3_x*o2_y*p3_y + a2_z*n3_x*o3_y*p2_y + a2_z*n3_y*o2_x*p2_y - a2_z*n3_y*o2_y*p2_x + a2_z*n3_y*o2_y*p3_x - a2_z*n3_y*o3_x*p2_y - a3_x*n2_y*o2_z*p3_y + a3_x*n2_y*o3_y*p2_z - a3_x*n2_y*o3_y*p3_z + a3_x*n2_y*o3_z*p3_y + a3_x*n2_z*o2_y*p3_y - a3_x*n2_z*o3_y*p2_y - a3_x*n3_y*o2_y*p2_z + a3_x*n3_y*o2_y*p3_z + a3_x*n3_y*o2_z*p2_y - a3_x*n3_y*o3_z*p2_y - a3_x*n3_z*o2_y*p3_y + a3_x*n3_z*o3_y*p2_y - a3_y*n2_x*o2_y*p2_z + a3_y*n2_x*o2_y*p3_z + a3_y*n2_x*o2_z*p2_y - a3_y*n2_x*o3_z*p2_y + a3_y*n2_y*o2_x*p2_z - a3_y*n2_y*o2_x*p3_z - a3_y*n2_y*o2_z*p2_x + a3_y*n2_y*o2_z*p3_x - a3_y*n2_y*o3_x*p2_z + a3_y*n2_y*o3_x*p3_z + a3_y*n2_y*o3_z*p2_x - a3_y*n2_y*o3_z*p3_x - a3_y*n2_z*o2_x*p2_y + a3_y*n2_z*o2_y*p2_x - a3_y*n2_z*o2_y*p3_x + a3_y*n2_z*o3_x*p2_y + a3_y*n3_x*o2_y*p2_z - a3_y*n3_x*o2_y*p3_z - a3_y*n3_x*o2_z*p2_y + a3_y*n3_x*o3_z*p2_y + a3_y*n3_z*o2_x*p2_y - a3_y*n3_z*o2_y*p2_x + a3_y*n3_z*o2_y*p3_x - a3_y*n3_z*o3_x*p2_y - a3_z*n2_x*o2_y*p3_y + a3_z*n2_x*o3_y*p2_y + a3_z*n2_y*o2_x*p3_y - a3_z*n2_y*o3_x*p3_y - a3_z*n2_y*o3_y*p2_x + a3_z*n2_y*o3_y*p3_x + a3_z*n3_x*o2_y*p3_y - a3_z*n3_x*o3_y*p2_y - a3_z*n3_y*o2_x*p2_y + a3_z*n3_y*o2_y*p2_x - a3_z*n3_y*o2_y*p3_x + a3_z*n3_y*o3_x*p2_y)/(a2_x*n2_y*o2_z - a2_x*n2_y*o3_z - a2_x*n2_z*o2_y + a2_x*n2_z*o3_y - a2_x*n3_y*o2_z + a2_x*n3_y*o3_z + a2_x*n3_z*o2_y - a2_x*n3_z*o3_y - a2_y*n2_x*o2_z + a2_y*n2_x*o3_z + a2_y*n2_z*o2_x - a2_y*n2_z*o3_x + a2_y*n3_x*o2_z - a2_y*n3_x*o3_z - a2_y*n3_z*o2_x + a2_y*n3_z*o3_x + a2_z*n2_x*o2_y - a2_z*n2_x*o3_y - a2_z*n2_y*o2_x + a2_z*n2_y*o3_x - a2_z*n3_x*o2_y + a2_z*n3_x*o3_y + a2_z*n3_y*o2_x - a2_z*n3_y*o3_x - a3_x*n2_y*o2_z + a3_x*n2_y*o3_z + a3_x*n2_z*o2_y - a3_x*n2_z*o3_y + a3_x*n3_y*o2_z - a3_x*n3_y*o3_z - a3_x*n3_z*o2_y + a3_x*n3_z*o3_y + a3_y*n2_x*o2_z - a3_y*n2_x*o3_z - a3_y*n2_z*o2_x + a3_y*n2_z*o3_x - a3_y*n3_x*o2_z + a3_y*n3_x*o3_z + a3_y*n3_z*o2_x - a3_y*n3_z*o3_x - a3_z*n2_x*o2_y + a3_z*n2_x*o3_y + a3_z*n2_y*o2_x - a3_z*n2_y*o3_x + a3_z*n3_x*o2_y - a3_z*n3_x*o3_y - a3_z*n3_y*o2_x + a3_z*n3_y*o3_x), (a2_x*n2_y*o2_z*p3_z - a2_x*n2_y*o3_z*p2_z - a2_x*n2_z*o2_y*p3_z + a2_x*n2_z*o3_y*p3_z + a2_x*n2_z*o3_z*p2_y - a2_x*n2_z*o3_z*p3_y - a2_x*n3_y*o2_z*p3_z + a2_x*n3_y*o3_z*p2_z + a2_x*n3_z*o2_y*p2_z - a2_x*n3_z*o2_z*p2_y + a2_x*n3_z*o2_z*p3_y - a2_x*n3_z*o3_y*p2_z - a2_y*n2_x*o2_z*p3_z + a2_y*n2_x*o3_z*p2_z + a2_y*n2_z*o2_x*p3_z - a2_y*n2_z*o3_x*p3_z - a2_y*n2_z*o3_z*p2_x + a2_y*n2_z*o3_z*p3_x + a2_y*n3_x*o2_z*p3_z - a2_y*n3_x*o3_z*p2_z - a2_y*n3_z*o2_x*p2_z + a2_y*n3_z*o2_z*p2_x - a2_y*n3_z*o2_z*p3_x + a2_y*n3_z*o3_x*p2_z + a2_z*n2_x*o2_y*p3_z - a2_z*n2_x*o3_y*p3_z - a2_z*n2_x*o3_z*p2_y + a2_z*n2_x*o3_z*p3_y - a2_z*n2_y*o2_x*p3_z + a2_z*n2_y*o3_x*p3_z + a2_z*n2_y*o3_z*p2_x - a2_z*n2_y*o3_z*p3_x - a2_z*n3_x*o2_y*p3_z + a2_z*n3_x*o3_y*p3_z + a2_z*n3_x*o3_z*p2_y - a2_z*n3_x*o3_z*p3_y + a2_z*n3_y*o2_x*p3_z - a2_z*n3_y*o3_x*p3_z - a2_z*n3_y*o3_z*p2_x + a2_z*n3_y*o3_z*p3_x + a2_z*n3_z*o2_x*p2_y - a2_z*n3_z*o2_x*p3_y - a2_z*n3_z*o2_y*p2_x + a2_z*n3_z*o2_y*p3_x - a2_z*n3_z*o3_x*p2_y + a2_z*n3_z*o3_x*p3_y + a2_z*n3_z*o3_y*p2_x - a2_z*n3_z*o3_y*p3_x - a3_x*n2_y*o2_z*p3_z + a3_x*n2_y*o3_z*p2_z + a3_x*n2_z*o2_y*p3_z - a3_x*n2_z*o3_y*p3_z - a3_x*n2_z*o3_z*p2_y + a3_x*n2_z*o3_z*p3_y + a3_x*n3_y*o2_z*p3_z - a3_x*n3_y*o3_z*p2_z - a3_x*n3_z*o2_y*p2_z + a3_x*n3_z*o2_z*p2_y - a3_x*n3_z*o2_z*p3_y + a3_x*n3_z*o3_y*p2_z + a3_y*n2_x*o2_z*p3_z - a3_y*n2_x*o3_z*p2_z - a3_y*n2_z*o2_x*p3_z + a3_y*n2_z*o3_x*p3_z + a3_y*n2_z*o3_z*p2_x - a3_y*n2_z*o3_z*p3_x - a3_y*n3_x*o2_z*p3_z + a3_y*n3_x*o3_z*p2_z + a3_y*n3_z*o2_x*p2_z - a3_y*n3_z*o2_z*p2_x + a3_y*n3_z*o2_z*p3_x - a3_y*n3_z*o3_x*p2_z - a3_z*n2_x*o2_y*p2_z + a3_z*n2_x*o2_z*p2_y - a3_z*n2_x*o2_z*p3_y + a3_z*n2_x*o3_y*p2_z + a3_z*n2_y*o2_x*p2_z - a3_z*n2_y*o2_z*p2_x + a3_z*n2_y*o2_z*p3_x - a3_z*n2_y*o3_x*p2_z - a3_z*n2_z*o2_x*p2_y + a3_z*n2_z*o2_x*p3_y + a3_z*n2_z*o2_y*p2_x - a3_z*n2_z*o2_y*p3_x + a3_z*n2_z*o3_x*p2_y - a3_z*n2_z*o3_x*p3_y - a3_z*n2_z*o3_y*p2_x + a3_z*n2_z*o3_y*p3_x + a3_z*n3_x*o2_y*p2_z - a3_z*n3_x*o2_z*p2_y + a3_z*n3_x*o2_z*p3_y - a3_z*n3_x*o3_y*p2_z - a3_z*n3_y*o2_x*p2_z + a3_z*n3_y*o2_z*p2_x - a3_z*n3_y*o2_z*p3_x + a3_z*n3_y*o3_x*p2_z)/(a2_x*n2_y*o2_z - a2_x*n2_y*o3_z - a2_x*n2_z*o2_y + a2_x*n2_z*o3_y - a2_x*n3_y*o2_z + a2_x*n3_y*o3_z + a2_x*n3_z*o2_y - a2_x*n3_z*o3_y - a2_y*n2_x*o2_z + a2_y*n2_x*o3_z + a2_y*n2_z*o2_x - a2_y*n2_z*o3_x + a2_y*n3_x*o2_z - a2_y*n3_x*o3_z - a2_y*n3_z*o2_x + a2_y*n3_z*o3_x + a2_z*n2_x*o2_y - a2_z*n2_x*o3_y - a2_z*n2_y*o2_x + a2_z*n2_y*o3_x - a2_z*n3_x*o2_y + a2_z*n3_x*o3_y + a2_z*n3_y*o2_x - a2_z*n3_y*o3_x - a3_x*n2_y*o2_z + a3_x*n2_y*o3_z + a3_x*n2_z*o2_y - a3_x*n2_z*o3_y + a3_x*n3_y*o2_z - a3_x*n3_y*o3_z - a3_x*n3_z*o2_y + a3_x*n3_z*o3_y + a3_y*n2_x*o2_z - a3_y*n2_x*o3_z - a3_y*n2_z*o2_x + a3_y*n2_z*o3_x - a3_y*n3_x*o2_z + a3_y*n3_x*o3_z + a3_y*n3_z*o2_x - a3_y*n3_z*o3_x - a3_z*n2_x*o2_y + a3_z*n2_x*o3_y + a3_z*n2_y*o2_x - a3_z*n2_y*o3_x + a3_z*n3_x*o2_y - a3_z*n3_x*o3_y - a3_z*n3_y*o2_x + a3_z*n3_y*o3_x)))'
```

Expanded that looks like:

```
FiniteSet(((a2_x*n2_y*o2_z*p3_x - a2_x*n2_y*o3_x*p2_z + a2_x*n2_y*o3_x*p3_z -
    a2_x*n2_y*o3_z*p3_x - a2_x*n2_z*o2_y*p3_x + a2_x*n2_z*o3_x*p2_y -
    a2_x*n2_z*o3_x*p3_y + a2_x*n2_z*o3_y*p3_x + a2_x*n3_x*o2_y*p2_z -
    a2_x*n3_x*o2_y*p3_z - a2_x*n3_x*o2_z*p2_y + a2_x*n3_x*o2_z*p3_y -
    a2_x*n3_x*o3_y*p2_z + a2_x*n3_x*o3_y*p3_z + a2_x*n3_x*o3_z*p2_y -
    a2_x*n3_x*o3_z*p3_y - a2_x*n3_y*o2_z*p3_x + a2_x*n3_y*o3_x*p2_z -
    a2_x*n3_y*o3_x*p3_z + a2_x*n3_y*o3_z*p3_x + a2_x*n3_z*o2_y*p3_x -
    a2_x*n3_z*o3_x*p2_y + a2_x*n3_z*o3_x*p3_y - a2_x*n3_z*o3_y*p3_x -
    a2_y*n2_x*o2_z*p3_x + a2_y*n2_x*o3_x*p2_z - a2_y*n2_x*o3_x*p3_z +
    a2_y*n2_x*o3_z*p3_x + a2_y*n2_z*o2_x*p3_x - a2_y*n2_z*o3_x*p2_x -
    a2_y*n3_x*o2_x*p2_z + a2_y*n3_x*o2_x*p3_z + a2_y*n3_x*o2_z*p2_x -
    a2_y*n3_x*o3_z*p2_x - a2_y*n3_z*o2_x*p3_x + a2_y*n3_z*o3_x*p2_x +
    a2_z*n2_x*o2_y*p3_x - a2_z*n2_x*o3_x*p2_y + a2_z*n2_x*o3_x*p3_y -
    a2_z*n2_x*o3_y*p3_x - a2_z*n2_y*o2_x*p3_x + a2_z*n2_y*o3_x*p2_x +
    a2_z*n3_x*o2_x*p2_y - a2_z*n3_x*o2_x*p3_y - a2_z*n3_x*o2_y*p2_x +
    a2_z*n3_x*o3_y*p2_x + a2_z*n3_y*o2_x*p3_x - a2_z*n3_y*o3_x*p2_x -
    a3_x*n2_x*o2_y*p2_z + a3_x*n2_x*o2_y*p3_z + a3_x*n2_x*o2_z*p2_y -
    a3_x*n2_x*o2_z*p3_y + a3_x*n2_x*o3_y*p2_z - a3_x*n2_x*o3_y*p3_z -
    a3_x*n2_x*o3_z*p2_y + a3_x*n2_x*o3_z*p3_y + a3_x*n2_y*o2_x*p2_z -
    a3_x*n2_y*o2_x*p3_z - a3_x*n2_y*o2_z*p2_x + a3_x*n2_y*o3_z*p2_x -
    a3_x*n2_z*o2_x*p2_y + a3_x*n2_z*o2_x*p3_y + a3_x*n2_z*o2_y*p2_x -
    a3_x*n2_z*o3_y*p2_x - a3_x*n3_y*o2_x*p2_z + a3_x*n3_y*o2_x*p3_z +
    a3_x*n3_y*o2_z*p2_x - a3_x*n3_y*o3_z*p2_x + a3_x*n3_z*o2_x*p2_y -
    a3_x*n3_z*o2_x*p3_y - a3_x*n3_z*o2_y*p2_x + a3_x*n3_z*o3_y*p2_x +
    a3_y*n2_x*o2_z*p3_x - a3_y*n2_x*o3_x*p2_z + a3_y*n2_x*o3_x*p3_z -
    a3_y*n2_x*o3_z*p3_x - a3_y*n2_z*o2_x*p3_x + a3_y*n2_z*o3_x*p2_x +
    a3_y*n3_x*o2_x*p2_z - a3_y*n3_x*o2_x*p3_z - a3_y*n3_x*o2_z*p2_x +
    a3_y*n3_x*o3_z*p2_x + a3_y*n3_z*o2_x*p3_x - a3_y*n3_z*o3_x*p2_x -
    a3_z*n2_x*o2_y*p3_x + a3_z*n2_x*o3_x*p2_y - a3_z*n2_x*o3_x*p3_y +
    a3_z*n2_x*o3_y*p3_x + a3_z*n2_y*o2_x*p3_x - a3_z*n2_y*o3_x*p2_x -
    a3_z*n3_x*o2_x*p2_y + a3_z*n3_x*o2_x*p3_y + a3_z*n3_x*o2_y*p2_x -
    a3_z*n3_x*o3_y*p2_x - a3_z*n3_y*o2_x*p3_x +
    a3_z*n3_y*o3_x*p2_x)/(a2_x*n2_y*o2_z - a2_x*n2_y*o3_z - a2_x*n2_z*o2_y +
    a2_x*n2_z*o3_y - a2_x*n3_y*o2_z + a2_x*n3_y*o3_z + a2_x*n3_z*o2_y -
    a2_x*n3_z*o3_y - a2_y*n2_x*o2_z + a2_y*n2_x*o3_z + a2_y*n2_z*o2_x -
    a2_y*n2_z*o3_x + a2_y*n3_x*o2_z - a2_y*n3_x*o3_z - a2_y*n3_z*o2_x +
    a2_y*n3_z*o3_x + a2_z*n2_x*o2_y - a2_z*n2_x*o3_y - a2_z*n2_y*o2_x +
    a2_z*n2_y*o3_x - a2_z*n3_x*o2_y + a2_z*n3_x*o3_y + a2_z*n3_y*o2_x -
    a2_z*n3_y*o3_x - a3_x*n2_y*o2_z + a3_x*n2_y*o3_z + a3_x*n2_z*o2_y -
    a3_x*n2_z*o3_y + a3_x*n3_y*o2_z - a3_x*n3_y*o3_z - a3_x*n3_z*o2_y +
    a3_x*n3_z*o3_y + a3_y*n2_x*o2_z - a3_y*n2_x*o3_z - a3_y*n2_z*o2_x +
    a3_y*n2_z*o3_x - a3_y*n3_x*o2_z + a3_y*n3_x*o3_z + a3_y*n3_z*o2_x -
    a3_y*n3_z*o3_x - a3_z*n2_x*o2_y + a3_z*n2_x*o3_y + a3_z*n2_y*o2_x -
    a3_z*n2_y*o3_x + a3_z*n3_x*o2_y - a3_z*n3_x*o3_y - a3_z*n3_y*o2_x +
    a3_z*n3_y*o3_x), (a2_x*n2_y*o2_z*p3_y - a2_x*n2_y*o3_y*p2_z +
    a2_x*n2_y*o3_y*p3_z - a2_x*n2_y*o3_z*p3_y - a2_x*n2_z*o2_y*p3_y +
    a2_x*n2_z*o3_y*p2_y + a2_x*n3_y*o2_y*p2_z - a2_x*n3_y*o2_y*p3_z -
    a2_x*n3_y*o2_z*p2_y + a2_x*n3_y*o3_z*p2_y + a2_x*n3_z*o2_y*p3_y -
    a2_x*n3_z*o3_y*p2_y - a2_y*n2_x*o2_z*p3_y + a2_y*n2_x*o3_y*p2_z -
    a2_y*n2_x*o3_y*p3_z + a2_y*n2_x*o3_z*p3_y + a2_y*n2_z*o2_x*p3_y -
    a2_y*n2_z*o3_x*p3_y - a2_y*n2_z*o3_y*p2_x + a2_y*n2_z*o3_y*p3_x +
    a2_y*n3_x*o2_z*p3_y - a2_y*n3_x*o3_y*p2_z + a2_y*n3_x*o3_y*p3_z -
    a2_y*n3_x*o3_z*p3_y - a2_y*n3_y*o2_x*p2_z + a2_y*n3_y*o2_x*p3_z +
    a2_y*n3_y*o2_z*p2_x - a2_y*n3_y*o2_z*p3_x + a2_y*n3_y*o3_x*p2_z -
    a2_y*n3_y*o3_x*p3_z - a2_y*n3_y*o3_z*p2_x + a2_y*n3_y*o3_z*p3_x -
    a2_y*n3_z*o2_x*p3_y + a2_y*n3_z*o3_x*p3_y + a2_y*n3_z*o3_y*p2_x -
    a2_y*n3_z*o3_y*p3_x + a2_z*n2_x*o2_y*p3_y - a2_z*n2_x*o3_y*p2_y -
    a2_z*n2_y*o2_x*p3_y + a2_z*n2_y*o3_x*p3_y + a2_z*n2_y*o3_y*p2_x -
    a2_z*n2_y*o3_y*p3_x - a2_z*n3_x*o2_y*p3_y + a2_z*n3_x*o3_y*p2_y +
    a2_z*n3_y*o2_x*p2_y - a2_z*n3_y*o2_y*p2_x + a2_z*n3_y*o2_y*p3_x -
    a2_z*n3_y*o3_x*p2_y - a3_x*n2_y*o2_z*p3_y + a3_x*n2_y*o3_y*p2_z -
    a3_x*n2_y*o3_y*p3_z + a3_x*n2_y*o3_z*p3_y + a3_x*n2_z*o2_y*p3_y -
    a3_x*n2_z*o3_y*p2_y - a3_x*n3_y*o2_y*p2_z + a3_x*n3_y*o2_y*p3_z +
    a3_x*n3_y*o2_z*p2_y - a3_x*n3_y*o3_z*p2_y - a3_x*n3_z*o2_y*p3_y +
    a3_x*n3_z*o3_y*p2_y - a3_y*n2_x*o2_y*p2_z + a3_y*n2_x*o2_y*p3_z +
    a3_y*n2_x*o2_z*p2_y - a3_y*n2_x*o3_z*p2_y + a3_y*n2_y*o2_x*p2_z -
    a3_y*n2_y*o2_x*p3_z - a3_y*n2_y*o2_z*p2_x + a3_y*n2_y*o2_z*p3_x -
    a3_y*n2_y*o3_x*p2_z + a3_y*n2_y*o3_x*p3_z + a3_y*n2_y*o3_z*p2_x -
    a3_y*n2_y*o3_z*p3_x - a3_y*n2_z*o2_x*p2_y + a3_y*n2_z*o2_y*p2_x -
    a3_y*n2_z*o2_y*p3_x + a3_y*n2_z*o3_x*p2_y + a3_y*n3_x*o2_y*p2_z -
    a3_y*n3_x*o2_y*p3_z - a3_y*n3_x*o2_z*p2_y + a3_y*n3_x*o3_z*p2_y +
    a3_y*n3_z*o2_x*p2_y - a3_y*n3_z*o2_y*p2_x + a3_y*n3_z*o2_y*p3_x -
    a3_y*n3_z*o3_x*p2_y - a3_z*n2_x*o2_y*p3_y + a3_z*n2_x*o3_y*p2_y +
    a3_z*n2_y*o2_x*p3_y - a3_z*n2_y*o3_x*p3_y - a3_z*n2_y*o3_y*p2_x +
    a3_z*n2_y*o3_y*p3_x + a3_z*n3_x*o2_y*p3_y - a3_z*n3_x*o3_y*p2_y -
    a3_z*n3_y*o2_x*p2_y + a3_z*n3_y*o2_y*p2_x - a3_z*n3_y*o2_y*p3_x +
    a3_z*n3_y*o3_x*p2_y)/(a2_x*n2_y*o2_z - a2_x*n2_y*o3_z -
    a2_x*n2_z*o2_y + a2_x*n2_z*o3_y - a2_x*n3_y*o2_z + a2_x*n3_y*o3_z +
    a2_x*n3_z*o2_y - a2_x*n3_z*o3_y - a2_y*n2_x*o2_z + a2_y*n2_x*o3_z +
    a2_y*n2_z*o2_x - a2_y*n2_z*o3_x + a2_y*n3_x*o2_z - a2_y*n3_x*o3_z -
    a2_y*n3_z*o2_x + a2_y*n3_z*o3_x + a2_z*n2_x*o2_y - a2_z*n2_x*o3_y -
    a2_z*n2_y*o2_x + a2_z*n2_y*o3_x - a2_z*n3_x*o2_y + a2_z*n3_x*o3_y +
    a2_z*n3_y*o2_x - a2_z*n3_y*o3_x - a3_x*n2_y*o2_z + a3_x*n2_y*o3_z +
    a3_x*n2_z*o2_y - a3_x*n2_z*o3_y + a3_x*n3_y*o2_z - a3_x*n3_y*o3_z -
    a3_x*n3_z*o2_y + a3_x*n3_z*o3_y + a3_y*n2_x*o2_z - a3_y*n2_x*o3_z -
    a3_y*n2_z*o2_x + a3_y*n2_z*o3_x - a3_y*n3_x*o2_z + a3_y*n3_x*o3_z +
    a3_y*n3_z*o2_x - a3_y*n3_z*o3_x - a3_z*n2_x*o2_y + a3_z*n2_x*o3_y +
    a3_z*n2_y*o2_x - a3_z*n2_y*o3_x + a3_z*n3_x*o2_y - a3_z*n3_x*o3_y -
    a3_z*n3_y*o2_x + a3_z*n3_y*o3_x), (a2_x*n2_y*o2_z*p3_z -
    a2_x*n2_y*o3_z*p2_z - a2_x*n2_z*o2_y*p3_z + a2_x*n2_z*o3_y*p3_z +
    a2_x*n2_z*o3_z*p2_y - a2_x*n2_z*o3_z*p3_y - a2_x*n3_y*o2_z*p3_z +
    a2_x*n3_y*o3_z*p2_z + a2_x*n3_z*o2_y*p2_z - a2_x*n3_z*o2_z*p2_y +
    a2_x*n3_z*o2_z*p3_y - a2_x*n3_z*o3_y*p2_z - a2_y*n2_x*o2_z*p3_z +
    a2_y*n2_x*o3_z*p2_z + a2_y*n2_z*o2_x*p3_z - a2_y*n2_z*o3_x*p3_z -
    a2_y*n2_z*o3_z*p2_x + a2_y*n2_z*o3_z*p3_x + a2_y*n3_x*o2_z*p3_z -
    a2_y*n3_x*o3_z*p2_z - a2_y*n3_z*o2_x*p2_z + a2_y*n3_z*o2_z*p2_x -
    a2_y*n3_z*o2_z*p3_x + a2_y*n3_z*o3_x*p2_z + a2_z*n2_x*o2_y*p3_z -
    a2_z*n2_x*o3_y*p3_z - a2_z*n2_x*o3_z*p2_y + a2_z*n2_x*o3_z*p3_y -
    a2_z*n2_y*o2_x*p3_z + a2_z*n2_y*o3_x*p3_z + a2_z*n2_y*o3_z*p2_x -
    a2_z*n2_y*o3_z*p3_x - a2_z*n3_x*o2_y*p3_z + a2_z*n3_x*o3_y*p3_z +
    a2_z*n3_x*o3_z*p2_y - a2_z*n3_x*o3_z*p3_y + a2_z*n3_y*o2_x*p3_z -
    a2_z*n3_y*o3_x*p3_z - a2_z*n3_y*o3_z*p2_x + a2_z*n3_y*o3_z*p3_x +
    a2_z*n3_z*o2_x*p2_y - a2_z*n3_z*o2_x*p3_y - a2_z*n3_z*o2_y*p2_x +
    a2_z*n3_z*o2_y*p3_x - a2_z*n3_z*o3_x*p2_y + a2_z*n3_z*o3_x*p3_y +
    a2_z*n3_z*o3_y*p2_x - a2_z*n3_z*o3_y*p3_x - a3_x*n2_y*o2_z*p3_z +
    a3_x*n2_y*o3_z*p2_z + a3_x*n2_z*o2_y*p3_z - a3_x*n2_z*o3_y*p3_z -
    a3_x*n2_z*o3_z*p2_y + a3_x*n2_z*o3_z*p3_y + a3_x*n3_y*o2_z*p3_z -
    a3_x*n3_y*o3_z*p2_z - a3_x*n3_z*o2_y*p2_z + a3_x*n3_z*o2_z*p2_y -
    a3_x*n3_z*o2_z*p3_y + a3_x*n3_z*o3_y*p2_z + a3_y*n2_x*o2_z*p3_z -
    a3_y*n2_x*o3_z*p2_z - a3_y*n2_z*o2_x*p3_z + a3_y*n2_z*o3_x*p3_z +
    a3_y*n2_z*o3_z*p2_x - a3_y*n2_z*o3_z*p3_x - a3_y*n3_x*o2_z*p3_z +
    a3_y*n3_x*o3_z*p2_z + a3_y*n3_z*o2_x*p2_z - a3_y*n3_z*o2_z*p2_x +
    a3_y*n3_z*o2_z*p3_x - a3_y*n3_z*o3_x*p2_z - a3_z*n2_x*o2_y*p2_z +
    a3_z*n2_x*o2_z*p2_y - a3_z*n2_x*o2_z*p3_y + a3_z*n2_x*o3_y*p2_z +
    a3_z*n2_y*o2_x*p2_z - a3_z*n2_y*o2_z*p2_x + a3_z*n2_y*o2_z*p3_x -
    a3_z*n2_y*o3_x*p2_z - a3_z*n2_z*o2_x*p2_y + a3_z*n2_z*o2_x*p3_y +
    a3_z*n2_z*o2_y*p2_x - a3_z*n2_z*o2_y*p3_x + a3_z*n2_z*o3_x*p2_y -
    a3_z*n2_z*o3_x*p3_y - a3_z*n2_z*o3_y*p2_x + a3_z*n2_z*o3_y*p3_x +
    a3_z*n3_x*o2_y*p2_z - a3_z*n3_x*o2_z*p2_y + a3_z*n3_x*o2_z*p3_y -
    a3_z*n3_x*o3_y*p2_z - a3_z*n3_y*o2_x*p2_z + a3_z*n3_y*o2_z*p2_x -
    a3_z*n3_y*o2_z*p3_x + a3_z*n3_y*o3_x*p2_z)/(a2_x*n2_y*o2_z -
    a2_x*n2_y*o3_z - a2_x*n2_z*o2_y + a2_x*n2_z*o3_y - a2_x*n3_y*o2_z +
    a2_x*n3_y*o3_z + a2_x*n3_z*o2_y - a2_x*n3_z*o3_y - a2_y*n2_x*o2_z +
    a2_y*n2_x*o3_z + a2_y*n2_z*o2_x - a2_y*n2_z*o3_x + a2_y*n3_x*o2_z -
    a2_y*n3_x*o3_z - a2_y*n3_z*o2_x + a2_y*n3_z*o3_x + a2_z*n2_x*o2_y -
    a2_z*n2_x*o3_y - a2_z*n2_y*o2_x + a2_z*n2_y*o3_x - a2_z*n3_x*o2_y +
    a2_z*n3_x*o3_y + a2_z*n3_y*o2_x - a2_z*n3_y*o3_x - a3_x*n2_y*o2_z +
    a3_x*n2_y*o3_z + a3_x*n2_z*o2_y - a3_x*n2_z*o3_y + a3_x*n3_y*o2_z -
    a3_x*n3_y*o3_z - a3_x*n3_z*o2_y + a3_x*n3_z*o3_y + a3_y*n2_x*o2_z
    - a3_y*n2_x*o3_z - a3_y*n2_z*o2_x + a3_y*n2_z*o3_x - a3_y*n3_x*o2_z +
    a3_y*n3_x*o3_z + a3_y*n3_z*o2_x - a3_y*n3_z*o3_x
    - a3_z*n2_x*o2_y + a3_z*n2_x*o3_y + a3_z*n2_y*o2_x - a3_z*n2_y*o3_x +
    a3_z*n3_x*o2_y - a3_z*n3_x*o3_y - a3_z*n3_y*o2_x + a3_z*n3_y*o3_x)))
```